# Corrupted Files Delete in Windows

Tags: windows-10, shell-script, ms-dos, sh, secure-erase

I am preparing a file using shell script and while doing some tests, I added the pause> nul line into my sh file. Then I ran the sh file, but there was a file named nul on the desktop and I can't delete it in any way. What would you suggest me to do? Thank you.

Note: I cannot change the name of the file, I cannot move the file to a different folder. I cannot delete the file, I try to delete the file permanently and it comes back again. I cannot open the file. (LSHIFT + RSHIFT + DEL)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbsfB.png)

[Windows 10 LTSC version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW0KK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first to restart in Safe Mode (use MSCONFIG to set the next restart to Safe Mode).  See if you can delete the file in Safe Mode.

Then if this does not work, there may be an issue with the locking handle.  In this case I use Unlocker (Major Geeks) to delete the file.

Good Luck.